# Oracle 11g PL/SQL query run back to back, with different results (not returning all rows)

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle11g

So, if I run a query back to back, on the same database, I retrieve different results. Nothing in the query changes, nothing in the database is changing and the rows are all there the entire time. I notice this generally on the first query of the day, and then going forward it will show me the rest of the rows. Any thoughts? I have been working on this for days, but with no luck.

Version: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

I don't think the issue is the query, but figured I would include it to help isolate.

```
SELECT stuff
FROM   datamartdbo.position_details e10010
       INNER JOIN datamartdbo.fund_master e10002
          ON (e10010.dmart_fund_id = e10002.dmart_fund_id)
       INNER JOIN datamartdbo.security_details e10013
          ON (    e10010.security_alias = e10013.security_alias
              AND e10002.effective_date = e10013.effective_date
              AND e10013.security_id NOT LIKE 'INTEREST ON CASHUSD%'
              AND e10002.snapshot_id = e10013.snapshot_id)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       (SELECT   fm.entity_id,
                 t.security_alias,
                 SUM (t.security_gain) - SUM (t.security_loss) tgainloss
        FROM     datamartdbo.fund_master fm
                 JOIN datamartdbo.trade_details t
                    ON fm.dmart_fund_id = t.dmart_fund_id
        WHERE        t.dmart_currency = 'BASE'
                 AND fm.entity_id IN (' an ENTITY ID here')
                 AND fm.effective_date BETWEEN 'Start DD-MON-YYYY'
                                           AND 'End DD-MON-YYYY'
        GROUP BY fm.entity_id, t.security_alias) gl
          ON     e10002.entity_id = gl.entity_id
             AND e10010.security_alias = gl.security_alias
WHERE      e10010.dmart_currency = 'BASE'
       AND (e10010.mkt_val <> 0 OR UPPER (e10013.investment_type) = 'FUTURES')
       AND e10010.local_book_value IS NOT NULL
       AND e10002.entity_id IN ('an ENTITY ID here')
       AND e10002.effective_date = 'End DD-MON-YYYY'
       AND e10002.snapshot_id = 'DEFAULT'
```

Comment: are you using sysdate for any of the date calculations?  This could explain different results when run at different times in the day.   There could be many reasons though.  How are you running this btw? How do you know its "not returning all rows"?

Comment: No sysdate in this query, static start and stop dates. This table isn't changing at all and I know the content that is there. I know it sounds crazy...

Comment: There is no PL/SQL in your example

Comment: Are any of the tables actually views, that might include calculations or call functions that could give weird side-effects?

Comment: Do you get different execution plans when you have different results?

Comment: Do you get different results if you do CTAS (`create table as select`)?

Comment: Trying to get execution plan results for an incorrect one, I may unfortunately have to wait until tomorrow.

Comment: Same plan hash value...

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are looking at subset of rows from a bigger result set. When ORACLE sends results to the client it does that in chanks (that could be configured) like 100, 1000, 10000 records.

My guess is that you looking at first (or first few) such chanks and see that they differer between runs. If you fetch the whole resultset, you cas examine them and see that they are the same, but when ORDER BY is not set, ORACLE is free to retrive records in any order.

Try to add ORDER BY constuction and I hope it will resolve the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not, this query is being used in reports and that's the only reason I am running it on the back-end now. I retrieve all rows when I am running this query or else it would default to just the 50 I have set up.    EDIT: * So the only reason I am running the query on the back-end is because it has the issue with apps accessing the same data

Comment: What does "used in reports" mean?  Is it possible that the report server is caching the results from an earlier run?

Comment: We have an application accessing the data and the query it is using is the one I provided. When I run the underlying query, I get the incorrect result generally the first time I run it that day, and the correct result after. So I was able to isolate it away from the application server, and directly to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that Oracle optimizer behaves differently. 
You may use hints, for example - NO_MERGE, 
or try to use WITH (materialize, inline) instead of subqueries